# Typescript/ESLint error: Unable to resolve path to module 'aws-lambda' import/no-unresolved

Tags: typescript, eslint, typescript-typings, typescript-eslint

I have a serverless project written with typescript. When I run ESLint I am getting the following error:

```
  1:85  error  Unable to resolve path to module 'aws-lambda'  import/no-unresolved
```

For the following line of code: `import { APIGatewayProxyEvent, APIGatewayProxyHandler, APIGatewayProxyResult } from 'aws-lambda';` (I have `"@types/aws-lambda": "^8.10.64"` in my devDependencies).

I don't understand what could be the error, as the typing is installed and if I try to import from "@types/aws-lambda" VS Code tells me to import from "aws-lambda" directly.

What am i doing wrong here please?

Comment: My webpack.config.js looks like this - https://github.com/serverless-heaven/serverless-webpack/blob/master/examples/typescript/webpack.config.js

Comment: https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/issues/1485

Comment: Unfortunately it did not help. I have added all my files to this public gist: https://gist.github.com/gomesp/045f35d82c501f4d6cd0124924330988#file-users-ts

Answer (score 6):

hendrixchord's anwser helped me to resolve the issue, but here is the trimmed down version of the necessary steps that really worked for me:

```sh
# It's a must, otherwise the below `settings` won't work:
$ npm install --save-dev eslint-import-resolver-typescript
# Not `--save-dev`.
$ npm install @types/aws-lambda
```

In the `.eslintrc` file (note that I'm using the `.js` version):

```
  settings: {
    'import/resolver': {
      typescript: {
        alwaysTryTypes: true,
      },
    },
  },
```

Comment: This seems to be the relevant issue: https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import/issues/1485
Still, I don't understand why @types/aws-lambda should not be placed in devDependencies. Any good reason for that?

Answer (score 4):

This is the config in my .eslintrc file

```
   "settings": {
        "import/parsers": {
            "@typescript-eslint/parser": [".ts", ".tsx"]
        },
        "import/resolver": {
            "typescript": {
                "alwaysTryTypes": true,
                "paths": "./tsconfig.json",
            },
        }
    },
```

Also I've noticed in your `tsconfig.json` file you've not included `typeRoots` since you've excluded `node_modules` in your `exclude` property. It should be like this

```
    "typeRoots": [
        "./node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "/node_modules/",
        ".serverless/**/*",
        ".webpack/**/*",
        "_warmup/**/*",
        "vscode/**/*",
        "lib/**/*",
        "tests"
    ]
```

If all of that fails the last resort would be to add it to the ignore list in `.eslintrc` file.

```
    "import/no-unresolved": [
        "error",
        {
            "ignore": [
                "aws-lambda"
            ]
        }
    ],
```

Answer (score 3):

If I use `AWSLambda.APIGatewayProxyEvent` when I define the type, it works for me:

```
const event: AWSLambda.APIGatewayProxyEvent = ...
```

I didn't have to modify anything.